# OpenJPA @FetchGroup

Tags: java, openjpa

I am using @FetchGroup to load category data, each category may or may not have parent/ child category.
*I only need 2 level of data, which means 
Category -> sub level1 -> sub level 2
*I do not want to fetch the complete try of category, since that will affect the performance.
I add 
`@FetchGroup(name = FetchGroupConstants.CATEGORY_CHILD_LEVEL_2, attributes = { 
            @FetchAttribute(name = "children", recursionDepth = 2) })`
at the entity class.
Then I also used the following group to fetch the data

`@FetchGroup(name = FetchGroupConstants.CATEGORY_BASIC, attributes = { 
            @FetchAttribute(name = "ordering"),
            @FetchAttribute(name = "catalog") }),`

Then I got the complete tree. The same result as "recursionDepth = -1".
If I set  recursionDepth = 1, I also get the complete tree.
I am using "FetchPlan"
What is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry it is openJPA not hibernate

Comment: Please post the code for your domain classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give up. I use fetch the whole tree into server's cache for now an.
Any suggestion.